# Spark SQL INSERTION TECHNIQUE for Result got from calculation

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

or insertion I'm using below code-

```
spark.sql("INSERT INTO countDirectorySize VALUES (`" +str(root) + "`)")
```

Entire code here for better understanding-

```
root = "/dbfs/mnt/datalake/.../"
spark.sql("INSERT INTO countDirectorySize VALUES (`" +str(root) + "`)")
```

This code gives error while inserting. Any help would be great.

Error:

```
    "cannot resolve '`/dbfs/mnt/datalake/.../`' given input columns: []; 
line 1 pos 30;\n'InsertIntoTable 'UnresolvedRelation `countSize`, false, false\n+- 'UnresolvedInlineTable [col1], [List('/dbfs/mnt/datalake/.../)]\n"
```

Comment: Why would you _not_ post the error?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Let me edit.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Edited

Comment: I don't know about spark sql, but in normal SQL you should list the columns you are inserting into: `INSERT INTO countDirectorySize (ColumnName) VALUES (....`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid this doesn't work. I checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked-
The arrangement. Just `('"____"')` is all I wanted to know.

```
spark.sql("INSERT INTO countDirectorySize VALUES ('"+str(root)+"')")
```